# Markdown issues

Tags: html, github, jupyter-notebook

I'm having an issue with Jupyter Notebooks and Github.
I found this issue both on Watson and VS Code.
When I set my initial headers, I would like to center them.
I created earlier notebooks without issue with Watson using

```html
<h1><center>Centered text!</center></h1>
```

Watson will still render this, but upon upload to Github, the notebook fails to load or loads without markdown.
I changed this to:

```html
# <center>my text</center>
```

This still works in both VS Code and Watson but fails upon uploading to Github.
If I adjust the markdown to exclude centering, the project loads.

Comment: Markup is there to structure the content sementically. For styling, like centering use CSS formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
<h1 align="center">Centered Heading</h1>
```